# Read not mapped fields with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Suppose database table `Customer` which is mapped to class `Customer` has more fields, then described in annotations.

Is it possible to read any of such not mapped fields?

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to map them to your Customer. You can create a second Customer object like   SpecialCustomer where you can map whatever you want that is not mapped in the Customer. If you have some field that distinguishes in between the two types of customer you can use @DiscriminatorColumn and value in addition.

Read the Hibernate Inheritance strategies. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/inheritance.html

Alternatively if you real really really dont want to map any extra classes and fields you have the option to use a NativeSQL query and Map the results to some structure of your choice.

http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/result-set-mapping-basics/

If I was in your place I would go for the SpecialCustomer approach.

Comment: Isn't it possible just to access underlying raw data somehow?

Comment: Absolutly not! Hibernate is generating SQL from the mappings. There is no such thing AS raw data in this particular case because the extra fields are not even contained within the resultset. Sory I understand IT is not the answer you hoped for.

Comment: Can't I customize SQL generating process to add required fields to resultset?

Comment: Even if you do this through lets say a custom HibernateLoader and dialect. Again you need to store them somewhere and we are back again from where we started. Mapping them.

Comment: I am not sure if you realize it but everytime you convert your resultset to business objects eventualy you are doing mapping. Now IT is your choice if you will do this mapping the regular way, or you will hack the underlying persistence provider. The more you hack the more plattform dependent your solution will be.